# Can't use the data I I fetched with graphQL queries in my Angular component

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client

How can I assign the string I got from the query to another string in the series object? The queries are working because I can do data binding of the result, but I don't know how to handle this data that got the result stored in.

Code shown below:

```
  data: "";  
  data1: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.apollo.query({
      query: gql`query {
            getActivity(deviceId:"ggh"){
                  activity
                }

      }`
    }).subscribe(({ data, loading }) => {
      this.data = data;
    });

    this.apollo.query({
      query: gql`query {
            getEvent(deviceId:"ggh", timeStart: "December 17, 1995 03:24:00"){
                  timeEnd
                }

      }`
    }).subscribe(({ data, loading }) => {
      this.data1 = data;
    });

    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: this.data,
          data: [
            {......
```

Comment: start with using 'query variables' (best for both queries), then use 'skip' option to wait for result of the 1st query

Comment: Yes but this doesn't help me with the data :(

Comment: learn to walk before running? you can learn only what you need but still you need to learn